# My reputation was reduced by 10, but there was no downvote on the post

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I don't know what happened. Is it a bug? Or is it some rules I still don't know?

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

[image]

Comment: unupvote != downvote

Comment: @Mysticial but what unupvote is ?

Comment: An unupvote is the act of removing an unupvote.

Comment: @Mysticial Do you mean it remove a upvote?

Comment: Yes. Someone upvoted you and you gained +10. Then the person removed the upvote. So you lose the 10 that you gained on it.

Comment: @Mysticial OK I understand now. So other question. how to close my question?

Comment: @Mysticial you better post this as answer, it's not so trivial. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An "unupvote" isn't the same as a "downvote". So don't confuse them.

- A "downvote", is a vote that nets you -2.
- An "unupvote", is the removal of an upvote.

In your case, you received an upvote for which you gained +10. Later on, the user removed that vote - thus you lose the +10 that you originally gained.

Comment: Thanks.:)  I think this is also a way to close question .